# cronjobs not working

Tags: php, unix, cron

For the past few hours I am struggling to make my cronJobs work. Believe me I googled everything and I even searched on stackoverflow but somehow the code I saw didnt work as expected. This is why I posted here.

I am doing this in SSH :

```
crontab -e
```

Then I edit my cronjob list and I add this :

```
MAILTO=myemail@serv.com
*   *   *   *   *   wget -q "http://www.mywebsite.com/path/to/cronJob.php"
```

I get no response on my email with the PHP response. PHP has an output if I call it from browser but I dont get anything on my email, but if I put an error in the cronJob, like removing the last quotes, I get email with the error.

Then I press CTRL+X , I save and then I restart nginx and nothing.

I checked with `crontab -l` and the cronjobs are there.

All I want to do is make an URL from my website get executed every 1 minute. If I call the URL from my browser it seems to work.

I have UBUNTU and nGinx

Any help ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `-O -`.

The problem is that by default, wget will save its result to a file. You want the content to be dumped to stdout.

This means you'll have to cleanup your working directory of all `cronJob.php.*` files lying around too ;)

So:

```
* * * * * wget -q -O - "http://www.mywebsite.com/path/to/cronJob.php"
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem. I had this in my code: require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/something/cronJob.php').

Apparently $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] was empty.

So I fixed this using :

$path = str_replace('/something/cronJob.php','',$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

Answer (score 0):

Here is a few steps to find out what is going wrong:

1. Make a script `MAILTO=myemail@serv.com` should be in that script and not in the crontab
2. Does that script run Ok from the command line?
3. Does `crontab` have the same environment variables